# Bison parser execution terminates depending on input file size

Tags: windows, bison, filesize, terminate

I created a parser using bison and scanner using flex to parse the setupapi.log file in windows. I tried executing the parser by taking small portions of the file and it worked through. It worked fine for file with about 20 lines. But when I added two more words to the last line of the body, it terminated there giving the error as .exe has stopped working.

How can I get rid of this.

I use %union in my bison file and memory is allocated using malloc from the flex file whenever an identifier is encountered.

My flex file is:

```
%{  
 #include <stdio.h>
#include "check.tab.h"
#include <string.h>
 #include<malloc.h>
int yyline=1;
 int i;

%}



identifier      [_a-zA-Z\.0-9:=&\\{}()\'\-]+
time            ([0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)

%%

"/"         {
            return(SLASH_TOK);
         }

"["         {
            return(OPEN_TOK);
         }

"]"         {
            return(CLOSE_TOK);
         }

">>>"       {
            return (START_TOK); 
        }

"<<<"       {
            return (END_TOK);
         }

"!!!"       {
            return(ERROR_TOK);
         }

  "!"           {
                return(WARN_TOK);
                }

   "...:"       {
                    return(VEND_INFO);
                }

   "bak:"       {
                    return(BAK_TOK);
                }

   "cci:"       {
                    return(CCI_TOK);
                }   



         //SOME MORE TOKENS ARE HERE....


"\n"        {
            yyline++;
        }

{time}      {
           yylval.sval = malloc(strlen(yytext)+1);
           printf("FRM LEXER TIME= %s %s\n",yytext,yylval.sval);
           strncpy(yylval.sval,yytext,strlen(yytext)+1);

            for(i=0;yylval.sval[i]!='\0';i++)
                 {
                        if(!(i<strlen(yytext)))
                        {
                         yylval.sval[i]='\0';
                        }
                }

                printf("FRM LEXER TIME= %s %s\n",yytext,yylval.sval);
                 return(TIME);
        }


[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\]+(\.)+[\.a-zA-Z_0-9:\\]* {printf("REACHED EXTRA\n");return(DATA);}


[a-zA-Z]+(\:)+[\.a-zA-Z_0-9:\\]*    {yylval.sval = malloc(strlen(yytext)+1);
                strncpy(yylval.sval,yytext,strlen(yytext)+1);
                printf("REACHED EXTRA\n");
                 for(i=0;yylval.sval[i]!='\0';i++)
                 {
                        if(!(i<strlen(yytext)))
                        {
                         yylval.sval[i]='\0';
                        }
                }
                return(DATA);
             }

{identifier}    {

                yylval.sval = malloc(strlen(yytext)+1);
                strncpy(yylval.sval,yytext,strlen(yytext)+1);
                //printf("YYTEXT=%s %d\n",yytext,strlen(yytext));

                for(i=0;yylval.sval[i]!='\0';i++)
                {
                        if(!(i<strlen(yytext)))
                        {
                         yylval.sval[i]='\0';
                        }
                }

                printf("FRM LEXER ID = %s %s\n",yytext,yylval.sval);
                return(IDENTIFIER);
             }

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
return 1;
}
```

My bison file is:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int yyline;
extern char* yytext;
FILE *fp;
%}

%union
{
    char *sval;
};

%token  SLASH_TOK   
 %token      OPEN_TOK
 %token     CLOSE_TOK 
 %token     START_TOK   
    //ALL TOKENS ARE HERE


%type <sval> boot_data description statements word date section_title time_stamp section_body log_entry evt_catgry evt_time


%start session
%%

session : boot_data section
        {
        printf("SESSION\n");
        fprintf(fp,"NO.OF LINES PARSED = %d\n",yyline);
    }
    ;

boot_data : description statements description boot_time
    {
            printf("BOOT DATA\n");
            fprintf(fp,"DESCRIPTION:%s\n",$1);
    }
     ;

description : OPEN_TOK statements CLOSE_TOK
    {
        $$=$2;
        printf("DESCRIPTION\n");
    }
    ;

boot_time: OPEN_TOK statements date TIME CLOSE_TOK
    {
        printf("BOOT TIME\n");
        fprintf(fp,"DATE:%s\n",$3);
        fprintf(fp,"TIME:%s\n",$4);
    }
    ;

date : IDENTIFIER SLASH_TOK IDENTIFIER SLASH_TOK IDENTIFIER
    {
        printf("DATE\n");
        $$=$1;
        strcat($$,"/");
        strcat($$,$3);
        strcat($$,"/");
        strcat($$,$5);
    }
     ;

statements : word
     {
            $$=$1;
            printf("STAETEMENT 1\n");
    }

    |statements word

    {

            $$=$1;
            strcat($$," ");
            strcat($$,$2);
            printf("statements 2\n");
    }
    ;

word : IDENTIFIER
    {
        printf("WORD=%s  %s\n",yytext, $$);

    } 
    |TIME
    {
         printf("TIME=%s  %s\n",yytext, $$);
         fprintf(fp,"%s",$$);

    }
    |DATA
     ;

section : section_head section_body section_tail

     {
            printf("Compilation_start\n");
    }

    ;

section_head : section_title time_stamp
    {
            printf("Compilation_start111\n");
     }
     ;

section_title :START_TOK OPEN_TOK statements CLOSE_TOK
    {
            printf("Compilation_start222\n");
            fprintf(fp,"%s\n",$3);
     }
      ;

time_stamp :START_TOK statements date TIME
    {
            printf("Compilation_start444\n");
            fprintf(fp,"%s Date: %s\n",$2,$3);
            fprintf(fp,"%s Time: %s\n\n",$2,$4);
    }
    ;


section_body :log_entry
        {
        printf("single  entry\n");

       }

      |section_body log_entry
     {
        printf("MULTIPLE ENTRIES\n");            
     }
     ;

log_entry :entry_prefix evt_time evt_catgry statements
    {
                    printf("no time stamp\n");  
                   // fprintf(fp,"====%s====\n",$3);
                    }
    ;




section_tail :section_foot exit_status 
    {
            printf("Compilation_start666\n");
    }
      ;

section_foot:  END_TOK statements date TIME
    {
            printf("Compilation_start777\n");
            fprintf(fp,"\n\n%s Date: %s\n",$2,$3);
            fprintf(fp,"%s Time: %s\n",$2,$4);
    }
    ;

 exit_status : END_TOK OPEN_TOK statements CLOSE_TOK
    {
            printf("Compilation_start888\n");
            fprintf(fp,"\n%s\n",$3);
    }
    ;


%%

yyerror(char *str)
{
printf("Parse error: %s at line %d ,",str,yyline);
yywhere(); 
}

yywhere()
{   
int colon=0;
int i;
if(yytext) 
{ 
    for(i=0;i<50;i++) if(!yytext[i] || yytext[i] == '\n') break;
    if(i)
    {  
        if(!colon)  
        { 
            printf(" near: \"%s\"\n",  yytext);
            colon = 1; 
        }
    }  
    printf("\n");
}  
}   

int main(void) 
{
int i =remove("output.txt");
fp=fopen("output.txt","a+");

yyparse();
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: How about simplifying your program and give us some code? And watch for the spot your error vanishes while simplifying. That might give you a clue to the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the strcat man page (should be valid for Windows as well):

> The  strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, 
>   overwriting the null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then
>   adds a terminating null byte.  The strings
>   may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result.

Now you're doing:

```
statements : word
     {
            $$=$1;
            printf("STAETEMENT 1\n");
    }

    |statements word    
    {

            $$=$1;
            strcat($$," ");
            strcat($$,$2);
            printf("statements 2\n");
    }
    ;
```

So if I assume you get an input of two words, the following happens:

After the first word, statements points to this word, because you do `$$ = $1`.
Then your scanner reads the next word and you concatenate a blank and the next word to the first word. But you didn't take precautions regarding the available memory.
You're programming in C which means you'll have to do about everything by yourself.

You could change the second action to something like:

```
statements : statements word
     {
            int lgth1 = strlen($$);
            int lgth2 = strlen($2);
            /* instead of malloc you could also realloc */
            char *tmp = (char *) malloc((lgth1 + lgth2 + 1 + 1) * sizeof(char));
            /* no error handling for clarity */
            sprintf(tmp, "%s %s", $$, $2); /* alternative: strcpy(); strcat(); strcat(); */
            free($$); free($2); /* freeing the memory not used any more */
            $$ = tmp;
    }
```

This of course isn't bullet proof code and you'll have to fix the other places as well.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your malloc doesn't leave space for the trailing NUL. Use `snprintf` instead of sprintf. Call it twice: the first time with length 0 to get the needed length, and the second time with that length after malloc'ing sufficient storage.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I missed the " " actually, not the \0, but the effect is the same. I think the overhead of snprintf() is larger than strlen() twice, but the advantage is that one doesn't forget to count the space character (or whatever characters are added). I'll edit the code

Comment: Alternately, use the commonly available though non-standard GNU/BSD `asprintf` function and the action becomes just `{ asprintf(&$$, "%s %s", $1, $2); free($1); free($2); }`

Comment: Never too old to learn :-) And thank you for the second correction